# Map function for custom n-ary tree

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get a mapping function like [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#Map) working for an n-ary tree, but am struggling.

```
data NTree a = Leaf a | Node a [NTree a]

ntreeMap :: (a -> b) -> NTree a -> NTree b
ntreeMap f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
ntreeMap f (Node y t) = Node (ntreeMap f y) (ntreeMap f t)
```

gives me

```
 Type error in application
*** Expression     : ntreeMap f t
*** Term           : t
*** Type           : [NTree b]
*** Does not match : NTree a
```

Could someone give me a pointer as to where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two problems here. One is that you need not invoke `ntreeMap` recursively for `y` in the `Node` case as it is of type `a` and not `NTree a`:

```
ntreeMap f (Node y t) = Node (f y) (ntreeMap f t)
```

The second one is that `t` is a list of trees and your function only maps over a single tree, so it should be

```
ntreeMap f (Node y t) = Node (f y) (map (ntreeMap f) t)
```

Answer (score 3):

BTW: Your type is a Functor.

An interesting thing about Functors is that there's only one way for a type to be a Functor (and adhering to the Functor laws).

Therefore Functor instances can be automatically derived:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.DeriveTH

data NTree a = Leaf a | Node a [NTree a]
$( derive makeFunctor ''NTree )

ntreeMap :: (a -> b) -> NTree a -> NTree b
ntreeMap = fmap
```

Comment: Just for completeness: You need the `derive` package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive) for this to work. Also, as of GHC 6.12 you can simply use `deriving Functor` in your code (by using the `-XDerivingFunctor` extension).

Answer (score 0):

While I think Rüdiger's answer is the best one I just wanted to add that in GHC 6.12 you can automatically derive a Functor instance for your datatype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE -DeriveFunctor #-}
data NTree a = Leaf a | Node a [NTree a]
  deriving Functor
```